# Position as a function of time with given Potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

Ok, so I have a given potential with

$$V(x) = \frac12\left(hx^2 + \frac{l}{x^2}\right)$$

where $h$ and $l$ are positive constants. Now I need to calculate the position $x(t)$ as a function of time.
I also know that $$\frac12m\dot x^2 + V(x) = E$$ where $E$ is just the total energy of the system.

This leaves me with the equation:

$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 = E - \frac12\left(hx^2 + \frac{l}{x^2}\right)$$

I have no clue how I can solve a differential equation like this.

Answer (score 1):

Given your equation for the conservation of energy, you know that: $$\frac{1}{2}m \dot{x}^2 + V(x) = E,$$ which can be rewritten as $$\dot{x} =\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{m}\Big(E-V(x)\Big)}.$$ You can "integrate" this equation: $$\int_{x_i}^{x} \frac{\text{d}x}{ \sqrt{\dfrac{2}{m}\Big(E-V(x) \Big)}} = \int_{t_i}^{t}\text{d}t.$$

In general, this would give you a solution of the form: $$f(x) = t.$$ Now, if you want to find $x$ as a function of $t$, one needs to invert the function $f$, which may not be always be possible. (Indeed, I do not think it is possible for the potential you mention.)

Comment: We used this method, to calculate the periodic duration. I will give this a try, maybe I can solve analytically for x(t)

Comment: I just gave it a couple of tries, doesn't look like it's possible. But good luck anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica gives

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{a-bx^2 - c/x^2}} = 
-\frac{\sqrt{-c + a x^2 - b x^4}
  }{(
 2 \sqrt{b} x \sqrt{a - (c + b x^4)/x^2})}  \arctan (a - 2 b x^2)/(2 \sqrt{b} \sqrt{-c + a x^2 - b x^4)}$$
Can you use that?

Comment: You can simplify it a bit more, you know. The term in the denominator cancels with the one in the numerator.

Comment: Thank you, but we are not allowed to use any kind of calculators or software.

Comment: I would be surprised if this integral is not in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik. You should be allowed to use that at least as I am pretty sure the question doesn’t not come from a calculus course.